# how many pages in the book?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help on the following question. I got the answer -620 can you please confirm.

On July 1st, Bill started to read a book recommended by friends, and, by reading the same number of pages each day of the month, managed to finish it on the 31st.

Another friend, Clare, also started reading the book at the same time.  She read a quarter of that
number of pages on the first of the month and, on each following day, one more page than on the
previous day. She also finished on the 31st.

How many pages did the book contain?

Comment: It's always dangerous to use "-" as a dash when doing math writing. Presumably, you mean you got the answer $620$?

Comment: Do you main Clare's initial reading speed is $\frac{1}{4}$ of the reading speed of Bill?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be the number of pages of the book. We are told that Bill reads $x/31$ pages each day, and that on the first day, Clare reads $x/124$ pages, and one more each subsequent day. But the formula for arithmetic series, The total number she reads can be written as $\frac{31(x+(x+30))}{2}$. This yields the linear equation $x=\frac{31(x/124+(x/124+30))}{2}$. This can be easily solved to give  $x=620$, so you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write such question in a math way to be able to solve anything...for example
Bill read $31 n$ pages during the period of 31 day. 
Clare read $n/4$ on first day, $n/4+1$ on second day, $n/4+2$ on third day etc.
Since they read the same book with the same number of pages we can write
$$31n = \sum_{i=1}^{31}\left(\frac{n}4+(i-1)\right)=\frac{31n}4+\sum_{i=0}^{30}i
$$
thus (I expect from you to understand the following steps by yourself)
$$31n-\frac{31n}4 = 31n\cdot\frac{3}4 = 31\cdot 15=465
$$
and therefore $$n=\frac{465\cdot 4}{93}=20$$

Finally you got $31n=620$ pages in the book.